# "Uninitialized constant User" for Factory_Girl Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to set up my Factory Girl factory for my users model and I can't seem to get it without some sort of error appearing. The error I'm getting now is "uninitialized constant User"

spec/factories.rb

```
factory :user do |user|

user.name "John Doe"
user.admin false
user.created_at Time.now
user.updated_at Time.now
user.password_digest nil
user.remember_token nil
user.e_admin nil
user.t_admin true
user.d_admin false
user.activated false
user.activated_at Time.now
end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require 'rails/all'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'factory_girl_rails'

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  config.disable_monkey_patching!
  config.warnings = true
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  config.profile_examples = 10

  config.order = :random
  Kernel.srand config.seed

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = [File.expand_path('../factories', __FILE__)]
  FactoryGirl.find_definitions

end
```

spec/user_spec.rb

```
require 'rspec'
require 'spec_helper'
require 'factory_girl_rails'


RSpec.describe 'Log In' do

  it 'should log user in' do

    var = create(:user)

    expect(var.valid?).to eql(true)
  end
 end
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this error?

```
  1) Log In should log user in
     Failure/Error: var = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant User
     # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `constantize'
     # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
     # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
     # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
     # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:26:in `build_class'
     # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:37:in `run'
     # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:23:in `run'
     # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
     # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:22:in `run'
     # /Users/ssuhli200/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `create'
     # ./spec/user_spec.rb:10:in `(root)'
```

Comment: You do have a User class in the app/models directory, right?

Comment: I don't think this will work, but try var = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

Comment: Did you run `rails generate rspec:install` after adding RSpec?

Comment: I don't think so, I didn't have "rails_helper.rb". I just ran it but I'm getting the same error. Do I have to add anything to rails_helper.rb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to add --require rails_helper to my .rspec file. And then I had to take out my "FactoryGirl.find_definitions" line because I was getting an error that I had more than one user factory. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your factory should look like this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "John Doe"
    admin false
    created_at Time.now
    updated_at Time.now
    password_digest nil
    remember_token nil
    e_admin nil
    t_admin true
    d_admin false
    activated false
    activated_at Time.now
  end
end
```

And in a folder structure - `spec/factories/user.rb`

Comment: Have you actually got a user.rb file in your models and run rake db:migrate to create the user? Have to ask :)

Comment: Yes, I do. I ran the migration again and still no luck.

Comment: Maybe include stack trace of the error in question. Might give some more insight into error.